# Sum of all numbers from many columns that match text from multiple rows in another column

Tags: google-sheets, formulas, google-sheets-query, google-sheets-arrayformula

I have some data from analytics that I need to combine somehow and trying to find the best way of doing this. I have data similar to the following:

| URL | Sessions |
| --- | --- |
| / | 59 |
| /?variable=1 | 2 |
| /?variable=2 | 37 |
| /?variable=3 | 1 |
| /another-page/ | 21 |
| /another-page/?variable=x | 1 |

I want to be able to find a way to first remove any UTM data (ie anything after the question mark) then add up the total sessions from each page. Here, the result I want is this:

| URL | Sessions |
| --- | --- |
| / | 99 |
| /another-page/ | 22 |

I want this formula to be automatic in the way that it read all URLs in Column A until it reaches the end.

Comment: Please remember that as per [site guidelines](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers) when an answer addresses your question, you should [accept](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/help/accepted-answer) it so others can benefit as well. You can even [upvote](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/help/why-vote) the answer. If you don't have enough reputation, your upvote will show up later, once you reach [enough reputation points](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/vote-up).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your source table is in columnns A & B of a sheet, you can use the following formula in any cell in any other column:

```
=arrayformula(query({{A1;regexreplace(A2:A,"\?.+",)},B:B},
"select Col1,sum(Col2) where Col1 is not null group by Col1 label sum(Col2) 'Sessions'",1))
```

The REGEXREPLACE finds a '?' with any number of characters following it and replaces the whole lot with null (i.e. it removes them). Then QUERY summarises by the result.

**EDIT**To sum more columns, reference them in the input array and then add additional 'sum(ColX)'s to the select clause, e.g for four columns to be summed:

```
=arrayformula(query({{A1;regexreplace(A2:A,"\?.+",)},B:E},
"select Col1,sum(Col2),sum(Col3),sum(Col4),sum(Col5) where Col1 is not null group by Col1",1))
```

Override the default column labelling of required using the label clause as shown in the first answer.

Comment: This works! How can I replicate this with another 5 columns of data (I only used two here for illustration)?

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean by 'another 5 columns' in relation to the above?

Comment: One column above is sessions, but have another 5 or so columns (ie bounce rate, average time per session, etc)

Comment: I've added additional explanation to the answer showing how to add additional columns to the query result.

Answer (score 0):

Another (easier to manage) way of doing this is:

```
=QUERY({INDEX(REGEXREPLACE(A2:A,"\?.+","")),
        BYROW(B2:D,LAMBDA(ss,SUM(ss)))},
            "select Col1, sum(Col2) where Col1<>'' 
             group by Col1 label sum(Col2) '' ")
```

*(**Do** adjust the formula according to your ranges and locale)*

If you want to extend to more columns you just change the range from `B2:D` *(3 columns)* to e.g. `B2:P` *(15 columns)*

In this formula we use `BYROW` to first sum all columns by row to just one column, `Col2`.
This way we avoid the repeating pattern `sum(Col2),sum(Col3),sum(Col4),sum(Col5), sum(Col6),sum(Col7),sum(Col8),sum(Col9)......` etc.

Comment: Since -after [your request](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/q/170364/#comment158187_170365) you altered your question, I took the liberty of changing the title to: **Sum of all numbers from many columns that match text from multiple rows in another column** You can change it back if you disagree.